# CouchDB: In a checklist app, new file for every list item?

Tags: couchdb

I'm working on a checklist web app

Now, every user can have lots of check lists, each with many items on them.

Would it be a good idea to keep the items **in a JS object** in the individual checklist? This would have been my first approach, since there wouldn't be a lot of sorting or anything happening on those items.

Now I'm thinking about putting every item **in an individual file** (because I might do stuff like deadlines and assignments for individual items)

This seems like a lot of files to me. Maybe I underestimate CouchDB. Would this be a good approach to the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Store every list item as new document.

Every list item document should have properties like `listname`, `deadline` and/or `assignment`.

You don't need (but you can have) extra docs to express hierarchy or nested relations. That what CouchDB views for - e.g. you will build a view `getListItemsByListname` with the `listname` as key to get all items of one list.